# PPC64/Power7 emulation on x86_64

Tags: x86-64, qemu, powerpc, playstation3

I have used CellSDK in past to emulate/debug and test code for powerpc7 architecture on x86_64 machines. Now i want to emulate test code for upcoming (Google/intel etc) PowerPC8 compiler is available, can someone tell me qemu that can emulate ppc64 on x86_64 so i can test code(scheduler) on it  .

Comment: The toolchain is available from
ftp://ftp.unicamp.br/pub/linuxpatch/toolchain/at/redhat/RHEL6/at7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum Requirement to emulate ppc kernel on Qemu is `qemu binaries` `kenrel image` and `rootfs`.

For arm its like this
`qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel zImage -hda rootfs.ext3  -no-reboot -show-cursor -usb -usbdevice wacom-tablet -no-reboot -serial stdio -m 256 --append "root=/dev/sda rw console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty mem=256M highres=off console=ttyS0"`

For more details on ppc_64 have a look at

`http://gmplib.org/~tege/qemu.html`

here `10 and 11`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use IBM SDK other than CellIDE.

https://www-304.ibm.com/webapp/set2/sas/f/lopdiags/sdklop.html

Also, if you are doing open source development, you can try to get a free access to real ppc64 machines. It works pretty well.

http://openpower.ic.unicamp.br/minicloud/